# Read whole file as text and not line wise in Python?

Tags: python

How to read entire text file as chunk of data or string? 
I do not want to read the file line by line instead read entire file as text and find count of certain words. What is the way to do that?

Comment: `contents = open('fname').read()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the file `read()` function "which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string".

Docs are [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Answer (score 1):

As for the second question, you might want to use a regex with [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
import re
with open("myfile.txt") as infile:
    text = infile.read()
regex = re.compile(r"\bsearchword\b", re.I) # case-insensitive
count = len(regex.findall(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`with`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and [`open.read`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) together:

```
with open("/path/to/file") as file:
    text = file.read()
```

`with` is a context manager that will auto-close the file for you when done.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it line by line, count the words you are interested in on each line, add the results to the subtotal, and print the total when you are done. Handy if the file you are processing is big enough to cause swapping.